# Changing background or foreground button color dynamically in android

Tags: android, xml, button, colors, onclick

Suppose I have a footer like the following in my app, defined in a XML file such as footer.xml:

```
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llfooter"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible" android:background="@drawable/fbg"
        android:weightSum="5.0" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">

        <Button android:id="@+id/home" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/home" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="10px"></Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/issue" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="10px"></Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/browse" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="10px"></Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/search" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/search" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="10px"></Button>

        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/favorite"
            android:background="@drawable/favorite" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:padding="10px"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Now, the problem is that *home*, *issue*, *browse*, etc. are PNG icons, and when I tap on them, user can't have feedback of touching, because they stay unchanged.

I would like to change background colour on pressing them (e.g. just a bit lighter). I know I can write down XML drawables () one per button, such as the following

```
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
      <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/bgalt" /> 
      <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" 
            android:drawable="@drawable/bgalt" /> 
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/bgnorm" /> 
  </selector>
```

.. but if I have 10 buttons (say, 5 for footer, 5 for header) I should create other 10 buttons with altered background (so more work with graph editor and .apk heavier because of more raster icons.. ).
Is there a way to create (even in java) a ligher color "onClick" and normal color "onRelease" instead, with only one icon per feature in resources?

Any suggestions?

Tnx in advance.
Gabo

Answer (score 0):

Use an ImageButton, and set the android:src parameter to the button drawable with a transparent background, then set the android:background value to a selector drawable that changes color when selected for example.

That way you have a set of drawables for your icons and one drawable only for the background which changes according to the state of your button

Comment: Thank you very much for your right answer, Jucas. It just works like I want right now!

Comment: @gabolander Please select this answer as the right one, if this answer has solved your question

Answer (score 0):

you can get button bitmap in onTouch in the code and change color, but it's bad idea. 
selector is best solution.